# Parse Excel document for keywords using C#

Tags: c#

I need to parse the excel document for certain keywords using C# and count the number of their occurrences. These keywords are required to be searched within a certain range, which is not fixed.

Please provide some help for this.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? How are you accessing Excel (ODBC, Interop, Office Open XML)?

Comment: I am using Interop. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in your C# code then the below source code will search in first row for the Excel sfilename is filename

```
int countOccurence = 0;

public bool SearchRows(string valTosearch)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
        try
        {
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            vk_filename = SFileName;

            //Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(SFileName);

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(
            SFileName, vk_update_links, vk_read_only,
            vk_format, vk_password,
            vk_write_res_password,
            vk_ignore_read_only_recommend, vk_origin,
            vk_delimiter, vk_editable, vk_notify,
            vk_converter, vk_add_to_mru,
            vk_local, vk_corrupt_load);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            // loop trough cell range and excel rows below will search in 1st row
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = xlRange.Worksheet;
            for (int iCount = 1; iCount <= colCount; iCount++)
            {

                string cellValue = "";
                string  fldValue = "";

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range fldRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, iCount];

                if (fldRange.Value2 != null)
                {
                    fldValue = fldRange.Value2.ToString().Trim().ToLower();
                }
                else
                {
                    fldValue = null;
                }
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CellRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[2, iCount];
                if (CellRange.Value2 != null)
                {
                    cellValue = CellRange.Value2.ToString().Trim().ToLower();
                    if (cellvalue == valtosearch)
                    { 
                       countOccurence +=1;
                    }                       
                }
                else
                {
                    cellValue = null;
                }

             }

            xlWorkbook.Close(vk_save_changes, vk_filename, vk_route_workbook);
            //xlWorkbook.Save();
            xlApp.Quit();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            xlApp.Quit();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this (i'm using Excel Interop here):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wk = app.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\testExcel.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet sh = (Excel.Worksheet)wk.ActiveSheet;

            Excel.Range rng = sh.get_Range("A1", "Z20");
            Console.WriteLine(CountWord(rng, "a"));

            wk.Close(false);
            app.Quit();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int CountWord(Excel.Range rng, string word)
        {
            int i = 0;

            Excel.Range rng1 = rng.Find(word);

            if (rng1 != null)
                i++;
            else
                return 0;

            string address = rng1.Address;

            Console.WriteLine(address);

            while (true)
            {
                rng1 = rng.FindNext(rng1);

                if (rng1 == null)
                    return i;

                Console.WriteLine(rng1.Address);

                if (rng1.Address == address)
                    return i;
                else
                    i++;            
            }
        }
    }
}
```